# Geting 411 error response from google fcm HTTP v1 api using php curl

Tags: firebase, http-headers, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, php-curl

I am trying to push notification from server to all android devices with the same topic calling Google firebase cloud messaging api,however, http response says 411 error code which stands for POST requests require a Content-length header, but I do add content-length in http post request header.I have googled the issue, and tried several ways, but it seems do not work.I use php version 7.0.I use postman to send the request, it was doing ok, even without header:content-type..

```
 $topic = 'topic';
    $projectId = 'projectid';
    $title = 'hahaha';
    $content = 'lol';

    $payload = array(
        'message' => array(
            'topic' => $topic,
            'notification' => array(
                'title' => $title,
                'body' => $content,
            )
        )
    );

    $json = json_encode(trim($payload));
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:Bearer '.$this->getFcmApiAccessToken(),
        'Content-Type: application/json; UTF-8',
        'Content-length:'.strlen($json),//'Content-length:0'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{$projectId}/messages:send");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($result);exit;
```

Comment: Headers are supposed to be case-insensitive, but try using `Content-Length` instead of `Content-length`.

Comment: @BobSnyder Yes I have tried, but does not work, what confuses me is I can send request without naming content-length in postman, but I cannot do the same thing using curl